# strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am assigning a token to user when he logs in, this token will be stored in database and will expire within 12 hours.

For this when the user logs in it will be shown in a view,

**my view is **

```
<a href=" <?php echo site_url('admin/checkval') ?> ">check valididty of token</a>
```

when he clicks on this,

**My Controller**

```
public function checkval(){

    $this->load->library('session');

    $goal = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $uid = $goal[0];
    $token = $goal[1];
    $this->load->model('loginmodel');

    $check_id = $this->loginmodel->token_valid($uid, $token);
    if($check_id){
      $data['query'] = $this->loginmodel->get_last_ten_entries();
       $this->load->view('admin/account', $data);
       print_r($data);
      echo "valid";
    }else {
        echo "invalid";
    }


 }
```

if his token is valid he will be shown list of users

**model**

```
public function token_valid($uid, $token){

  $responce = $this->db->query("SELECT expired_at FROM user_auth 
                                WHERE id = '$uid' AND token = '$token'");
  $date = strtotime($responce->result());
  echo "$date";
  $cdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $cdate = strtotime($cdate);
  $interval = date_diff($date,$cdate);
  $hour = $interval->h;
  if(h<12){
    return TRUE;
  }else {
  return FALSE;  // code...
  }

}
```

**database**

In user_auth table i have,

```
id int(50),token varchar(500),expired_at datetime
```

but when i do this, the error occurs as follows,

> strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given
>
> Trying to get property of non-object0
>
> Use of undefined constant h - assumed 'h'

I think once the first error is resolved, others will go away.
How do i do that? What am i doing wrong here?
Thank you for your suggesions

Comment: Please `var_dump` your `$responce->result()` this seems to be an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Return a `row()` instead of `result()`, your model should be like this :*

and date in `date_diff()` should be the DateTime objects from the `date_create()`

```
   public function token_valid($uid, $token)
   {
      $this->db->select('expired_at');
      $this->db->from('user_auth');
      $this->db->where('id',$uid);
      $this->db->where('token',$token);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
          $expired_date = $query->row()->expired_at;

          $expired_date = date_create($expired_date);
          $cdate = date_create('now');
          $interval = date_diff($expired_date,$cdate);
          $hour = $interval->h;
          if($hour < 12)
          {
            return TRUE;
          }else 
          {
            return FALSE;  
          }
      }   
   }
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: first and last errors are gone but 2nd and 3rd still remain at  `$interval = date_diff($date,$cdate);`            error is saying _date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, integer given_ and at  `$hour = $interval->h;`        saying  _Trying to get property of non-object_

Comment: thank you it worked.. all errors are gone but now it is showing invalid

Comment: date in database ie. expired_at = 2018-06-11 04:23:48

Comment: so what is invalid here

Comment: difference between current date and expired_date is less than 12 hours , still it is showing invalid. ie.$check_id value in check_val() in controller must be false

Comment: what do you mean by invalid,

Comment: in the loop in checkval() in controller we have stated, if diffrence between current date and expired_date is more than 12 hours, echo invalid. But in our case the diffrence between current date which is 2018-06-10 16:40:02 and expired date which is 2018-06-11 04:23:48 is just 17 minutes so it should echo valid but instead it is echoing invalid

Comment: when i echo $hour its coming out be 17

Comment: date time depends on server time and in turn depends on timezone so make sure u r in your timezone

Comment: your if condition should be like this :`if($check_id === TRUE)
    {
      echo "valid";
    }
    else 
    {
      echo "invalid";
    }`

Comment: for that i am doing - `if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
          date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
      }
      $expired_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('+12 hours'));`

Comment: changed the if condition still same result - 17 invalid

Answer (score 0):

`$responce->result()` return an object or an array

See doc : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

If you are sure to have just one row :

```
$row = $responce->result()
$date = strtotime($row->expired_at);
```